# experimental decorator warning in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, experimental-design

I am new to Angular2

When I renaming some file like app.states.ts to app.routes.ts
then my editor is showing warning on one of my Componet. Result coming perfect, 
I did n't understood that why I am getting this warning.

I am using **WEBSTROM** IDe

This this [image]

Please help me to remove this warning

Comment: Same warnings both in Webstorm and VS code even if "experimentalDecorators" is set to true, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add this option to your `tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem and I solved it, when I find 2 files "package.json" in project folder and in folder "UI". I removed file from "UI" folder and everything went properly.